# How to pass credentials through code instead of requesting user

Tags: text-to-speech, ibm-watson, speech-synthesis

I want to pass credentials thru code instead of requesting user to give credentials thru this prompt.

[image: Screenshot]

Although I'm passing credentials in header as given in below code:

```
<html>
<head>    
</head>
<body>
    <div id="text-to-speech">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>

        <input type="text" name="speech-text" TextMode="MultiLine" height:50px;">
        <input type="button" id="btnPOst" value="Play" />
        <br /><br /><br />
        <audio id="speech" autoplay preload="auto" autobuffer controls class="audio"></audio>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            debugger;
            $("#btnPOst").click(function () {
                debugger;
                var username= "";  
                var password = "";
                var request = $("#text-to-speech input[name=speech-text]").val();

                var url = "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api/v1/synthesize?voice=en-US_MichaelVoice&accept=audio/wav&text=" + request;                     
                $.ajax
                  ({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: url,
                      dataType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                      headers: {
                          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                          'Accept': 'audio/wav',
                          'Authorization': ("Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password))
                      },

                      success: function (content) {

                      },

                  });

                $("#speech").attr("src", url)[0].play();

            });
        });


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

hi @akash it is not a good practice to do basic authentication directly from the webpage since the credentials will be publicly available and that is a big security issue. Have you thought of using tokens instead? For production apps the recommended a approach is to do basic auth from a server side app that generates tokens, then webpages get those tokens from the server app and connect directly to the STT service. Tokens are valid for one hour. Of course you will need your own authentication mechanism between the webpage and your server app so you deliver tokens in a controlled way.

Please see this: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-javascript-sdk which is used to build this webpage: https://speech-to-text-demo.mybluemix.net/

Answer (score 0):

You can build a dynamic url like this:

"https://"+username+":"+password+"@gateway.watsonplatform.net/retrieve-and-rank/api/v1/solr_clusters

Comment: Just because you can, doesn't mean you should. Having it in the web page means a random person can steal the details and have the OP pay for all their unauthorised usage.

Comment: Valid point. Never spent deeper thoughts on this kind of topic and I will consider this in future implementations. But a random person is exaggerated, right? You still need access to a router, proxy or cache server.